# Center Bootstrap li elements on center of responsive page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get all of the elements in the navbar to always display in the center of the navbar and thus the center of the page, but still they are pulling to the left. When I remove my bootstrap libary, they are centered, so there is a conflict somewhere but I am not sure what and I want to use bootstrap.

My custom CSS is also linked AFTER the bootstrap one.

Any great is greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.nav {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav  li {
    display:inline;
}

.nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background: #900000;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: is there any particular purpose of using nested .container-fluid and .container classes?

Comment: Probably not, other than the fact it would allow it to align with the jumbotron as opposed to the edge of the page. I picked up an old project that's why they are there. They can be removed as long as the elements are centered on the page.

Comment: @markoffden: Centering via auto margins only works for block elements. If you want to center an `inline-block` element, that can be done via `text-align` on the parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap's css floats `.navbar-nav` to the left. Hence:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You need to overwrite this property. I suggest giving a unique class maybe like .myNav and resetting this float. Also adding a `display:inline-block`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav myNav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myNav{
float:none;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Finally, add a text-align:center to the wrapping navbar element to center the content inside

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thought I was along the right lines just wasn't sure where the pulling to the left was occurring exactly. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: My pleasure! Word of advice, always check your browser's developer tool to check the CSS. You will find this really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-center {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav  li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.nav a {
    padding:10px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background: #900000;
    border: none;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2ska9ym/